# how to remove progress dialog while using asynctask in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i have used asynctask in my programme i have dismiss dialog before intent is passed in postexecute method but in other activity data displays but it still display progress dialog how to remove or what is problem my code is at

http://pastebin.com/bGrMbGCJ

Comment: why you are start activity for result. startActivityForResult(in,0);

Comment: check your if statement whether the condition is fullfied and next time is better to paste code here ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to clear any existing dialog window, use:

```
dialog.cancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not have two spinner at a time. Need to use any trick in this case,

Use one common flag set on PostExecute.
Before step#3, on postExecute of both AsyncTask check the flag is already set, if yes just cancel the spinner.
Refer below pseudo code.

```
postExecute(){
      If(taskCompletedFlag == true){
            //Code to cancel the spinner.
            taskCompletedFlag = false;
      }else{
            taskCompledtedFlag = true;
      }
}
```

P.S. - In case you are not aware which AsyncTask will initiate first, you can use same mechanism over there.